# Why Bison gives Conflict: 2 Shift Reduce error

Tags: compiler-construction, bison, context-free-grammar

I'm trying below YACC grammar part but it gives me, what is the wrong with this? and how can I solve it? are there some rules to define grammar in Bison/ YACC ?

```
C:\Users\Dilan\Documents\LexProgram\miniProject>bison -dy videostore.y
conflicts: 1 shift/reduce
```

and my YACC code is :

```
%start VideoStore
%token title
%token type
%token name
%token days


%%

VideoStore  :   MOVIES CUSTOMERS
        |  CUSTOMERS MOVIES  
        |  MOVIES
        |  CUSTOMERS
        ;


MOVIES      :   MOVIES MOVIE
        |   MOVIE
        ;

MOVIE       :   title type RENTALS2
        ;

RENTALS2    :   RENTALS2 RENTAL2
        |   RENTAL2
        ;

RENTAL2     :   CUSTOMER1
        ;


CUSTOMER1   :   name days
        ;

CUSTOMERS   :   CUSTOMERS CUSTOMER
        |   CUSTOMER
        ;

CUSTOMER    :   name days RENTALS
        ;
RENTALS     :   RENTALS RENTAL
        |   RENTAL
        ;

RENTAL      :   MOVIE1
        ;

MOVIE1      :   title type
        ;

%%
int trace=0;
```

My problem is VideoStore.y: conflicts: 2 shift/reduce
and how can wrote LEX for this ?

Comment: Do you have an example input file for this? Basically, the warning means your language has ambiguities. It may or may not work. The larger problem will be that you're not using keywords and your lexer would need to identify wheter a string is a customer name or a movie title. Suggestion: Use XML for this instead.

Comment: What are the keywords lexer would need? and. I have gone through https://cis.uab.edu/softcom/GrammarInference/publications/scesm2005.pdf   this research sheet and I want to try this grammar, not all the research sheet. I'm learning this

Comment: The lexer doesn't need keywords, the parser does. The lexer only sees sequences of characters, so any text would probably be parsed as a "string" (instead of either a title or a name), which would give more ambiguities still. As noted in the answer, you have to introduce some terminal tokens into your file, such as delimiters or parenthesis around a group of things.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-v` option to `bison`, which gives you a .output file showing all the states and where any conflicts are.  In you case, you have conflicts in states 16 and 20:

```
state 16

    7 MOVIE: title type RENTALS2 .
    8 RENTALS2: RENTALS2 . RENTAL2

    name  shift, and go to state 15

    name      [reduce using rule 7 (MOVIE)]
    $default  reduce using rule 7 (MOVIE)

    RENTAL2    go to state 24
    CUSTOMER1  go to state 18
```

This tells you that the problem is that the parser can't figure out where the end of a `MOVIE` rule is with a single token of lookahead -- the `MOVIE` ends with a sequence of one or more `RENTAL2` rules, but since a `RENTAL2` begins with a `name` and things that come after a `MOVIE` (such as a `CUSTOMER` rule) also start with `name` it can't tell whether it should be trying to match more `RENTAL2`s or not.

Most commonly, you would fix this by using some sort of delimiter at the end of your `RENTALS2` list, such as a `';'`

Comment: Dear Chris Dodd, can you explain little more please, then how do I want to edit the program ?